# JQuery and PHP pressing enter to process

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, keydown, enter

I have the following two files request.php and response.php. I used to send the request using a button

```
    <input type="button" value="Request message" onclick="post()"/>
```

but now I and considering using just the "Enter"(13) key.

The code works, however it shows the result just for a couple of milliseconds. In theory keydown function is working and getting the result from response, bt I dont know why just for a very short time.

Any tips?

request.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function post(){
$("#message").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var message=document.getElementById("message").value;
    $.post('response.php',{postmessage:message},
    function(data){
    var result = $('#post_message').html(data);
    console
return result; });
    }
});
}
</script>

<form>
Enter Message:<input type="text" id="message" name="message" onclick="post()"/><br/>
</form>
<div id="post_message"></div>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

response.php

```
<?php
 function returnString() {
    $post_msg = $_POST['postmessage'];
    echo "Message entered ->", $post_msg ," <- here";
}
returnString();
?>
```

Comment: Message reflects in short period of time?

Comment: You don't have to write `onclick` function as you have defined `keydown` function with `if` statement.

Comment: _“however it shows the result just for a couple of milliseconds”_ - that’s because your form gets automatically submitted the “normal” way, because you did nothing to properly prevent that. You should rather bind a submit handler to your form here, than trying to listing for keyboard events - browsers will submit a form that contains only a single text field automatically, when enter is pressed while the cursor is in that field. And then prevent the default submit action the usual way (go research that, if you don’t know how to.)

Comment: Plus, your current setup makes rather little sense to begin with, because you would be adding a new additional keydown handler every time the field gets clicked.

Comment: @misorude you are right a simply submit would make more sense than listening for the keyboard. This is just a part of the code though, this will be used in a much larger page. Thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to mimic behavior that is already available by default
 with a form that only has one input.

Thus your form is submitting and reloading the page.

You don't need to listen to key event on the `<input>`. Just listen for the `submit` event of the `form` and prevent the default submit process

```js
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    var msg = $('#message').val();

    mockPost(msg).then(function(res){        
      $('#post_message').append('<p>' + res + '<p>')
    });    

})


function mockPost(v){
   return new Promise(function(resolve){
        setTimeout(function(){
          resolve('Message= ' + v)
        }, 200)
   })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
Enter Message:<input type="text" id="message" name="message"/><br/>
</form>
<div id="post_message"></div>
```

Comment: thanks thats much more clear. Looks good on the snippet however for some reason it wont work on my browsers opera and firefox for linux.

Comment: Make sure to use document.ready if code is in head. This will work on any browser , even 12 year old ones

Comment: That was the missing piece. works great. Although I dont need it, I like the fact that the entered text are "logged" without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

When you hit enter, the form is submitted. Just add e.preventDefault(), this way:

```
function post(){
$("#message").keydown(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var message=document.getElementById("message").value;
    $.post('response.php',{postmessage:message},
    function(data){
    var result = $('#post_message').html(data);
    console
return result; });
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah i tried the prevent method before but it does lock the whole message field and you cant type anything.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the suggestions. So I ended up with this code, just as suggested by @misorude . Simply adding a preventDefault and using submit in form.
I added an "onclick" on submit in case the user wants to submit by hitting the button. 
The response.php stays the same.

request.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function post(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    var message = $('#message').val();
    $.post('response.php',{postmessage:message},
    function(data){
    var result = $('#post_message').html(data);
    console
    return result; });
    });
}
</script>

<form>

Enter Message:<input type="text" id="message" name="message"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="post()">
</form>
<div id="post_message"></div>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: This will add a new submit event listener every time  the input is clicked. Asking for problems doing that